# SQL query returning NULL record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have been puzzled by the output I am getting from the query below
[Null Record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3T9b.png)

```
select    
    a14.TRD_VEH_VEHICLE_AGG_NAME  TRD_VEH_VEHICLE_AGG_NAME,
    sum(a11.STR_WEIGHT)  WJXBFS1
from
    VEH_SALES_FACT_NEW_USACNS_VW a11
join        
    SLS_SALESTIME_SDP_LKUP a12 on (a11.SALES_DATE_KEY = a12.SALES_DATE_KEY)
join        
    TRADE_VEH_PROFILE_NEW a13 on (a11.TRD_VEH_PRFL_KEY = a13.TRD_VEH_PRFL_KEY)
join        
    PIN_AGG_TRD_VEH_VEHICLE a14 on (a13.TRD_TRIM_LEVEL_KEY = a14.TRD_TRIM_LEVEL_KEY)
where   
    (a14.TRD_VEH_VEHICLE_AGG_NAME in ('Trade Vehicles usa') 
     and a12.SALES_MONTH_YYYYMM in ('201609')
    )
group by 
    a14.TRD_VEH_VEHICLE_AGG_NAME
```

This query as you can see returns a null record, and I am trying to insert the result into a temp table and it fails complaining that I am trying to insert a null into a not null column (TRD_VEH_VEHICLE_AGG_NAME).

I am perplexed as to how the null record is coming in the first place since there are no qualifying records. Can somebody solve this mystery?

[Query with resultset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Pxyv.png)

Comment: do you have an example of a sample record that should be included? We can't see the data

Comment: Please click on the link to see the output

Comment: Why do you believe that the out come of the query cannot be null?

Comment: You even stated that there are no qualifying records. So what makes you think there will be records to return? Sample data would be good to see from all tables.

Comment: @WEI_DBA I would expect no records to come up instead of NULL record, there is a difference between no records and null

Comment: @DVT i never said it should not be null, my question is how is it returning nulls instead of no records, there is a difference between a null record and no record. Also the column TRD_VEH_VEHICLE_AGG_NAME is  a not null column in the table so where is it getting the null from

Comment: Where's the insert statement?  My guess is your values doesn't align to your attributes somewhere; or some variable assignment is failing resulting in a null variable when you expect it to be a value.

Comment: @xQbert It is select into #temptable, I did not include it since the query fails if I did

Comment: Ok so this is a `select * into #tempTable from (YourQuery) as X`?  Perhaps just add `where TRD_VEH_VEHICLE_AGG_NAME is not null`  but your right I don't know why you would need it...

Comment: Try running the query once again and see if you still have the same result. I encountered the cases in the past where the SSMS froze and weird things (old rows) got displayed on the screen.

Comment: please do me a favor and run this: `select a14.TRD_VEH_VEHICLE_AGG_NAME
from VEH_SALES_FACT_NEW_USACNS_VW a11
join SLS_SALESTIME_SDP_LKUP a12 on (a11.SALES_DATE_KEY = a12.SALES_DATE_KEY)
join TRADE_VEH_PROFILE_NEW a13 on (a11.TRD_VEH_PRFL_KEY = a13.TRD_VEH_PRFL_KEY)
join PIN_AGG_TRD_VEH_VEHICLE a14 on (a13.TRD_TRIM_LEVEL_KEY = a14.TRD_TRIM_LEVEL_KEY)
group by a14.TRD_VEH_VEHICLE_AGG_NAME
ORDER BY TRD_VEH_VEHICLE_AGG_NAME` if you get NULL as first row then you do have records with NULL values hence NULL record as a result

Comment: @user2065377 i ran the query i don't see any nulls in the resultset